# Подключение к БД на ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Всем привет! Не могу решить проблему подключения к БД в asp.net MVC. Создал стандартный шаблон MVC в студии на .Net фреймворке, создал класс контекста данных, выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в файле web.config добавил в  строку подключения, выглядит следующим образом:

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AssetContext" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|\Assetsdb.mdf';Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Если базу данных сгенерировать через инициализатор и переопределение метода Seed т.е. программно, то подключается прекрасно, но этот вариант мне не подходит, т.к. нужна БД, которая будет в себе сохранять данные, а не каждый раз генерировать новую.
[image: Расположение базы данных в проекте]

Есть предположение, что это происходит потому что я каким-то образом использую подход code-first, но это не точно, пожалуйста, подскажите как можно подключить базу данных к проекту? Может я что-то делаю не правильно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавьте в вопрос класс в котором Вы  работаете с экземпляром AssetContext, так же вместо скринов лучше приводить код и ошибки текстом

Comment: Дело в том, что ошибок компиляции не было, только в дебаге если отлавливать. Большое спасибо за ваш ответ! Я учту свои недочеты! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем привет! Решение проблемы было очень банальным и простым, если у кого-то возникнет такая проблема, то:

При подключении к базе данных ваша таблица должна называться во множественном числе. Именно таблица.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вышло, что  у меня создалось новое подключение к необходимой мне базе с названием Table и к пустой (созданной при компиляции) таблице Assets. Т.к. объем данных у меня не большой, я ручками снова внес эти данные и все прекрасно заработало, если объем данных большой, то придётся пересоздавать таблицу!

Всем успехов в программировании!